# Android: move images between gridviews

Tags: android, image, gridview, drag

i need to implement this scene, but i don't know how to approach it:

[image: gridview]

the black rectangle are two gridviews, the blu square are images, the red one are only for show a placeholder to you).

i need to drag the images between gridviews to let the user choose 4-5 images (they go in the red square)... so drag from top to bottom and from bottom to top (select and unselect).
anyone can help me??

Answer (score 0):

you can easily done it by implementing OnTouchListener and OnDragListener in your activity.
ex-create shape_droptarget.xml and shape.xml in drawable folder.I have implemented it for my own work. I hope it will give you some help.

shape_droptarget.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFF0000" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

shape.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#FFFFFFFF" />

    <gradient
        android:angle="225"
        android:endColor="#DD2ECCFA"
        android:startColor="#DD000000" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp" />

</shape>
```

create draglayout.xml file in layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

  <GridLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/darkred"
      android:columnCount="2"
      android:columnWidth="300dp"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:rowCount="2"
      android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomleft"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomright"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
  <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
    >
    </View>
  <GridLayout 
      android:background="@color/darkgreen"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="4"
    android:columnWidth="300dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:rowCount="1"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topleft1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage11"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/topright1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage21"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomleft1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage31"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomright1"
        android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_column="3"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:background="@drawable/shape" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/myimage41"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

create an activity DragActivity

```
public class DragActivity extends Activity {



  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.draglayout);
    findViewById(R.id.myimage1).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage2).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage3).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage4).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomleft).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomright).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());


    findViewById(R.id.myimage11).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage21).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage31).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.myimage41).setOnTouchListener(new MyTouchListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topleft1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.topright1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomleft1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
    findViewById(R.id.bottomright1).setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
  }

  private final class MyTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
      if (motionEvent.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        ClipData data = ClipData.newPlainText("", "");
        DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(data, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }

  class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener {
    Drawable enterShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape_droptarget);
    Drawable normalShape = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shape);

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
      int action = event.getAction();
      switch (event.getAction()) {
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
        // do nothing
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(enterShape);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
        // Dropped, reassign View to ViewGroup
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        owner.removeView(view);
        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) v;
        container.addView(view);
        view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        break;
      case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
        v.setBackgroundDrawable(normalShape);
      default:
        break;
      }
      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

now you can move image from one grid to another and within the grid also.

Comment: yes but you see that if i drag an image, when dragged the image remain ALSO in the old place (like a duplicate)

Comment: Image is moving as you the pointer and it is moving with the pointer.can you explain more what you exactly want to do.Also you can set the imageview height and width equal to parent because as your requirement it should not move in its own container.better you remove the android:src from the imageview of second grid in xml file.